# If Linux is used as a kernel in most devices today then why does my Ubuntu suffer from driver issues?

Tags: drivers, kernel, compatibility

After I switched to Ubuntu permanently, I was satisfied overall except for one thing which annoyed me a lot: driver compatibility.

I use a ThinkPad L50 and extra mouse buttons do not work in Ubuntu. Generally, why do Linux OSes suffer from such problems when Linux is used to connect the software and the hardware for so many things?

Comment: "linux ist used to connect the software and the hardware for most things" is neither conceptually completely clear nor true. Unfortunately, availability of drivers for closed source hardware depends on the willingness of the hardware vendor to support a platform. Reverse engineering is cumbersome and often does not lead to perfect results.

Comment: Basically, the two things Bruni said: vendor choice and tediousness of reverse engineering.  I'd throw in third one: cost of support.

Comment: @Bruni isnt a "kernel" what connects the software and the hardware?

Comment: @Huzo no, it is a kernel. It does not mean it has to know all hardwares. It provides the "connections" required by drivers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system) as you can see in the picture it is what is "in between" applications and the hardwares. You still need drivers. The application asks the kernel which may provide access and let you call a driver depending on the user rights of the user who started the application et.c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think the best answer to this is that Ubuntu doesn't suffer from drivers.  The Lenovo Trackpoint IS supported in Ubuntu AND in the kernel but it needs to be configured first. In fact Lenovo is a Linux Foundation Silver member so most all their hardware should work.

So Ubuntu doesn't suffer from drivers, but from configuration files for hardware that got overlooked.

I did a quick google search on How to configure the Lenovo Trackpoint in Ubuntu and found immediately a YouTube film showing how to do it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-6yM4i_Iyc

And quite clear instructions you can copy paste from the same info one sees in the video.
https://pastebin.com/HX87RpNF

(Note: I didn't copy over the instructions and used link as they are only supporting to the question and not the main point of the question)

Comment: Thank you for looking it up. It is funny though however, I receive an error saying Permission Denied when I try to echo the values. Editing the configuration file did not change anything either. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Alexander if you tweak it, it does what you want it to. If you install a closed driver, it does what the manufacturer wants it to do. Linux and OSS is about giving people choices.

Answer (score 3):

Because Linux is used for most of the things... except workstations where its market share is between 1% and 5% IIRC.

I use Linux on a Thinkpad and extra mouse buttons do work fine though (Logitech Anywhere MX and Logitech M705). It fact the mouse is better supported on Linux, because out of the box the battery level dialog shows the battery level for the PC, but also for the mouse...

The problem may not be your Thinkpad but your mouse. At least one mouse from Logitech (M560) has mouse buttons mapped not to USB mouse events but to USB **keyboard** sequences that are specific to Win8+ desktops. This mouse is unusable on Linux (and OSX).

Comment: I see your point, but the "extra mouse buttons" that I meant was the trackpoint and the two mouse buttons for the trackpoint. It used to be fine right before I had switched. And not only that, but when I connect my Android Phone to my laptop, I face problems again.

Comment: Linux desktop environments usually allow the user to redefine and add key combinations so you could just set up your computer to respond to whatever the mouse is sending. I wouldn't say unusable, just inconvenient.